# Faster method to download 6.5m objects from GCP bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm looking for a *faster* method to download a ton of objects (6.5 million in my case) from a bucket. The average object size is 2kb (it's a JSON file). The method I used was `gsutil -m cp -r gs://<bucket>/<folder> .` which **took 14 hours for 1M objects**.

It's not feasible to run this on my laptop for 7 days straight. Any ideas?

PS: I don't need them to be in individual JSON files. I'm thinking to create a script that pulls a file from the bucket, and adds a row to a CSV, then deletes the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try downloading the files to a VM, compressing the files into a single tgz (or bz2 or xz), upload back to the bucket, and download the tgz.

Cloud shell should work too.

Comment: Using the same script and just waiting a week for it?

Comment: usually one big file is faster than the same volume of tiny files.  Add to that, you've compressed the data (json is quite compressible), and you'll find that your thruput would be much better.  Basic math tells me you're only dealing with 6.5m*2k = 12g which should compress using bz2 to 1.2g.  Even on a moderate connection, that should be overnight at the worst.

Comment: Your idea of converting to CSV also has merit - if you can discard an additional 20% of data you might even get the overall file size under 1g.

Comment: You could also use the [rsync](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) option to have a restartable transfer of the volume of tiny files, so it'd be a week's worth of transfer overnights only.

Comment: But no two ways about it -- you always have to deal with size*speed as an upper limit.